# How can I toggle "Apply same settings to global secondary indexes" using code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, boto3, autoscaling

I'm working with Boto3 to create my tables in DynamoDB. I have enabled auto scaling using the following code:

```
def conf_auto_scaling(self, table_name):
    print("INFO :: Creating auto scaling for Table [%s]" % table_name)

    # Read capacity
    self.as_c.register_scalable_target(ServiceNamespace='dynamodb',
                                       ResourceId='table/%s' % table_name,
                                       ScalableDimension='dynamodb:table:ReadCapacityUnits',
                                       MinCapacity=5,
                                       MaxCapacity=4000)
    # Write capacity
    self.as_c.register_scalable_target(ServiceNamespace='dynamodb',
                                       ResourceId='table/%s' % table_name,
                                       ScalableDimension='dynamodb:table:WriteCapacityUnits',
                                       MinCapacity=5,
                                       MaxCapacity=1000)

    percent_of_use_to_aim_for = 70.0
    scale_out_cooldown_in_seconds = 60
    scale_in_cooldown_in_seconds = 60
    self.as_c.put_scaling_policy(ServiceNamespace='dynamodb',
                                 ResourceId='table/%s' % table_name,
                                 PolicyType='TargetTrackingScaling',
                                 PolicyName='ScaleDynamoDBReadCapacityUtilization',
                                 ScalableDimension='dynamodb:table:ReadCapacityUnits',
                                 TargetTrackingScalingPolicyConfiguration={
                                     'TargetValue': percent_of_use_to_aim_for,
                                     'PredefinedMetricSpecification': {
                                         'PredefinedMetricType': 'DynamoDBReadCapacityUtilization'
                                     },
                                     'ScaleOutCooldown': scale_out_cooldown_in_seconds,
                                     'ScaleInCooldown': scale_in_cooldown_in_seconds
                                 })
    self.as_c.put_scaling_policy(ServiceNamespace='dynamodb',
                                 ResourceId='table/%s' % table_name,
                                 PolicyType='TargetTrackingScaling',
                                 PolicyName='ScaleDynamoDBWriteCapacityUtilization',
                                 ScalableDimension='dynamodb:table:WriteCapacityUnits',
                                 TargetTrackingScalingPolicyConfiguration={
                                     'TargetValue': percent_of_use_to_aim_for,
                                     'PredefinedMetricSpecification': {
                                         'PredefinedMetricType': 'DynamoDBWriteCapacityUtilization'
                                     },
                                     'ScaleOutCooldown': scale_out_cooldown_in_seconds,
                                     'ScaleInCooldown': scale_in_cooldown_in_seconds
                                 })
```

How can I enable the option "Apply same settings to global secondary indexes"?

[image: Apply same settings to global secondary indexes]

Answer (score 1):

Besides the code required for setting the scaling policy at the "table" level, you also have code at the "index" level.

So, for setting the scaling policy at the "index" level, you should call **put_scaling_policy**, but with different values for **ResourceId** and **ScalableDimension**:

For example:

```
auto_scaling_client.put_scaling_policy(
            ServiceNamespace='dynamodb',
            ResourceId=f'table/{PUT-HERE-YOUR-TABLE NAME}/index/{YOUR-INDEX-NAME}',
            PolicyType='TargetTrackingScaling',
            PolicyName='ScaleDynamoDBWriteCapacityUtilization',
            ScalableDimension='dynamodb:index:WriteCapacityUnits',
            TargetTrackingScalingPolicyConfiguration={
                'TargetValue': percent_of_use_to_aim_for,
                'PredefinedMetricSpecification': {
                    'PredefinedMetricType': 'DynamoDBWriteCapacityUtilization'
                },
                'ScaleOutCooldown': scale_out_cooldown_in_seconds,
                'ScaleInCooldown': scale_in_cooldown_in_seconds
            }
```

Please note that:

- The **ResourceId** receives the **full index name**
- The **ScalableDimensions** contains *index* instead of *table*, i.e.: 
  dynamodb:**index**:WriteCapacityUnits instead of dynamodb:**table**:WriteCapacityUnits